# ElementTree XPath - Getting all tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, elementtree

I am having trouble using XPath Selector in ElementTree. Is there a way to dynamically change how data is being extracted using the example below.

Let's say I am parsing through a file and I want to extract all the text within the target. Is there a way to use one call to use one "child".find(.//target/*) call that when looping through would both get the text in /target/p/em, /target/, /target/*, /target/**
In my real problem I have a ton of different data and want to be able to add it to a dictionary to reference it later
ie

```
page_values = {
 'first': child.find('.//first-name').text or "",
 'last': child.find('.//last-name').text or "",
 'biography': child.find('.//biography').text or ""
}
```

and I run into problems when the biography has tons of formatting applied to it so I would have to call it like

```
'biography': child.find('.//biography/p/em').text or ""
```

and the next time through the loop I would need to call it like

```
'biography': child.find(.//biography/).text or ""
```

Sample code:

**XML**

```
<root>
 <target>
  <p>
   <em>text</em>
  </p>
 </target>
</root>
```

vs

```
<root>
 <target>
  text
 </target>
</root>
```

Comment: Does your actual XML have `<target>` instead of `</target>`? If so, what you're running into is etree making a wild guess at how to parse some invalid XML, which usually doesn't turn out very well.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you just want all descendants no matter how deep, instead of just immediate children, use `//` or `//*` as appropriate instead of `/*`. But your example only has immediate children of `target` (there is no `target/p/em`; you have `<p></p>` followed by `<em>text</em>`, so `em` is not a child of `p`, despite the misleading indentation), so that's not going to be any different. Maybe the problem you're asking about is just that you're using `find` instead of `findall`, so you only get the first child instead of all of them?

Comment: Finally, do you maybe just want to `itertext` the `target` node, instead of trying to figure out how to use XPath to filter its descendants with an empty filter, and then how to get all the text from all of them?

Comment: Have you tried `/root/target//text()`? This retrieves _all_ text node descendants of `target`.

Comment: @abarnert Wow I didn't see that but both the <target> instead of </target> and <p></p><em>text</em> instead of <p><em>text</em></p> were a mistake and are now fixed, thanks!

Comment: OK, but please read all the other comments above and make it more obvious which of those is closest to what you want and why it isn't exactly what you want, because I'm still unclear.

Comment: None of these worked out, instead used BeautifulSoup to parse the html file and get the text.